# Facing problem in partitioning an unallocated disk

Tags: windows-7, laptop, partitioning

When I am creating the simple volume of an unallocated disk it changes into a dynamic disk, but after that a warning comes saying something like "Dynamic disk has not been supported on this version of Windows OS or Server, dynamic disk has not been supported on clusters."

I'm using Windows 7 Home Basic.

Answer (score 2):

It does that if you have 4 Primary Partitions you need to rework your setup so its 3 Primary partitions and 1 Extended Partition that you can put Logical Volumes in. I am guessing you are using a major manufacturer brand like HP or Dell. They seems to think its a good idea to setup 4 Primary partitions by default.